# How to select an elements second child without selecting it's first child's children

Tags: javascript, html

I'll explain my question better here. I want to get the second child of my main div without getting the first child's children.

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="child">
        <div id="problem"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

Using vanilla JavaScript is there a way I am able to grab the second "#child" from "#main". I can't use document.getElementById('child') because I have the other elements with that id, and I can't change either of the elements. I tried using document.getElementById('main').getElementsByTagName('div')[1], but then it gives the child of the first div to me. So I could but a '2' instead of the 1, Which would work but I am constantly adding and removing elements inside of ("#child"). So I would have to constantly change the number.

Is there any other way I can get select the second child? Thanks for taking time to help!

Comment: There is no `#firstChild` in the HTML you have provided. It is also not a good practice to use same Id for multiple elements

Comment: Your problem is duplicating `id`'s, you should never duplicate an `id`.

Comment: Lets say that these ID's were classes, now is there a way I am able to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use `class` instead of `id` because `id` must be unique. Then, use these code.

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll("#main > .child")

let secondElement = elements[1];
console.log("secondChild -->", secondElement.innerText)


let secondChild = Array.from(elements).find((element, index) => index == 1)
console.log("secondChild -->", secondChild.innerText)
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div class="child">
    <div id="problem">First</div>
    <div class="child">First Inner</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">Second</div>
  <div class="child">Third</div>
  <div class="child">
  <div class="child">Second Inner</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

#### querySelectorAll

> The Element method querySelectorAll() returns a static (not live)
>   NodeList representing a list of the document's elements that match the
>   specified group of selectors.-   [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

---

#### "#main > .child"

> The child combinator (>) is placed between two CSS selectors. It matches only those elements matched by the second selector that are the children of elements matched by the first. - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors)

Comment: What is there is a <div class="child"></div> inside of the first child div. Would all of this still work? Or would document.getElementsByClassName("child")[1] select  the child inside of the first child's div?

Comment: @JoeTheHobo No. In that case use querySelectorAll()

Comment: Some useful documentation links:

- [Document.querySelectorAll() - Web APIs | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)
- [CSS Selectors Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Answer (score 0):

`document.querySelector()` allows you to use CSS selectors.
So a simple `document.querySelector( '#main div:nth-child(2)' )` should do the trick.

But you should still remove any duplicate id attributes.

```js
const second_child = document.querySelector( '#main *:nth-child(2)' );
console.log( second_child.innerHTML );
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="child1">
      first
    <div id="problem"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="child2">second</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain to me what exactly is happening with '#main *:nth-child(2)'. Is there a way I can replace the #main with a variable of an element I already have?

Comment: It's the same syntax you write CSS code with. Or JQuery selectors. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll `#main` selects the element with the id main, then `*:nth-child(2)` selects the second element inside #main, whatever it is. You can replace #Main with anything else, a different id, a class name, a tag name. Just go read up on querySelectorAll. It does everything getElementById, getElementsByClassName and getElementsByTagName does, but with way more options, since almost all CSS selectors are supported.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can have your child of main element. Get all `Nodes` by using 
`querySelectorAll` and iterate through all nodes.

```js
var childs= document.getElementById("main").querySelectorAll("div");  
//console.log(childs);
childs[0]//first
childs[1]//second
childs.forEach(function(element,idx) {
  console.log(`element ${idx+1}` );
  console.log(element)
});

function getNthChild(elementAt){
 if(elementAt>0){
  console.log(childs[elementAt-1]);
 }
}
getNthChild(1);
```

```html
<div id="main">
    <div id="child">
        <div id="problem"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```